# Can a person be "misbehaved"?

Tags: passive-voice, transitivity

I saw a comment to [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/170519/my-son-daughter-or-our-son-daughter) that says:

> There is a running joke in English that when a child **is misbehaved**, they're "your child", when they're being a good child, they're "our child" or "my child". – AJFaraday Jun 27 at 8:15

It prompted me to wonder if the commenter had a typo and actually meant "*has* misbehaved", or a person can actually be misbehaved. I know "misbehave" can be used transitively as in

> Students shouldn't misbehave themselves.

But can it be used in passive voice or used predicatively, as in the comment? What does "that kid is misbehaved" mean?

I found a handful more examples of "misbehave" in passive constructions in Google Books:

> The **misbehaved user** is still able to achieve better success probability than normal users by accessing the slot with greater probability than the agreed value. (as opposed to **misbehaving**, note: this paper doesn't seem to be penned by native speakers of English)
>
> A Not-Trusted node is a **misbehaved node** and should be avoided and deprived of services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be a simple mistake (the writer started to say "is misbehaving", but changed their mind half way)

However it could be the use of the adjective "misbehaved", which means the same as "badly behaved".  It is a little non-standard in this use, and "badly behaved" is probably a better way to express this idea.